# How to obtain attributes of the regressor used in sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn's IterativeImputer with verious estimators, such as ExtraTreesRegressor. I would like to somehow get some attributes of the fit, such as oob_score, but I am not sure if it is possible and how. The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html) is not very informative.

Basically, I do something like that (X_missing is a matrix with missing values that is imputed):

```
imp = IterativeImputer(max_iter=10,estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=10,bootstrap=True,oob_score=True,verbose=1),verbose=True) 
imp.fit(X_missing)
imputed_df = imp.transform(X_missing)
```